# Shortest path algorithm for an analog clock

Tags: algorithm, math

I've got a c homework problem that is doing my head in and will be greatful if anyone can help point me in the right direction.

If I have two minutes points on an analog watch such as t1 (55 minutes) and t2 (7 minutes), I need to calculate the shortest amount of steps between the two points.

What I've come up with so far is these two equations:

```
-t1 + t2 + 60 =
    -55 + 7 + 60 
    = 12

t1 - t2 + 60 = 
    55 - 7 + 60 
    = 108

12 is lower then 108, therefore 12 steps is the shortest distance.
```

This appears to work fine if I compare the two results and use the lowest. However, if I pick out another two points for example let t1 = 39 and t2 = 34 and plug them into the equation:

```
-t1 + t2 + 60 = -39 + 34 + 60 = 55
t1 - t2 + 60 = 39 - 34 + 60 = 35

35 is lower then 55, therefore 35 steps is the shortest distance.
```

However, 35 isn't the correct answer. 5 steps is the shorest distance (39 - 34 = 5).

My brain is a little fried, and I know I am missing something simple. Can anyone help?

[image: Analog clock face]

Comment: +1 for asking a clear question, and disclosing up front that it is homework. :)

Comment: `t1 - t2 + 60 = 39 - 34 + 60 = 35` is not correct: the result should be `65`.  Edward Z. Yang answered the question, though, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is addition and subtraction modulo 60. Check out the `%` operator. Make sure you handle negatives correctly.

Comment: Thanks Edward, got my head around the problem now and getting the correct results!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use % operator, try to think this way:
for each couple of points (t1; t2), you'll have two way to connect them: one path will cross 0 (12 o'clock), and the other won't.

**Provided that t2 >= t1**, the second distance is easy to calculate: it's t2 - t1. 
the other distance is t1 + 60 - t2

I think your mistake was adding 60 in the first expression.