# Finding next position in 'circular' array

Tags: c#, arrays, math, unity-game-engine

I have an array of 8 compass points numbered from SW, clockwise though to S:

```
2 3 4
1   5
0 7 6
```

I want to calculate if the shortest route from one point to another would be clockwise (+1) or anticlockwise (-1). E.g. to go from 7 to 5 would be -1, to go from 7 to 0 would be + 1.

Simple problem I guess but I'm having a real brain freeze today.

The closest I've got is `if abs(start - end) < 4, -1, 1` but that doesn't work if the start is 3.

There is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214907/shortest-path-algorithm-for-an-analog-clock), the accepted answer for which is to use modulo, but doesn't explain how. I've thrown various calculations around without success.

Comment: 7 to 5 would be -2, no?

Comment: @Magnetron Yes :) But I'm just after the relative direction, positive or negative.

Comment: Oh, I got it now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `abs`, add `8` (the number of entries) and then take modulo `8`, like this:

```
enum Direction {
     None, Clockwise, Counterclockwise
}

public static Direction GetDirection(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return Direction.None;
    }
    return (a-b+8)%8 > 4 ? Direction.Clockwise : Direction.Counterclockwise;
}
```

Adding `8` makes the difference non-negative; modulo-`8` brings it into `0`...`7` range.

Note that when the number of steps is `4`, it does not matter which way you go, so the program prefers counterclockwise. You can change it by using `>=` in place of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int start=3;
int end=6;

var temp = start-end;
temp= temp < 0 ? temp + 7 : temp;

var result = temp < 4 ? -1 : 1;
```